# Highcharts styledMode with highcharts.css import causes pie legend hover to apply to all legend items

Tags: highcharts

Using [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/), if you create a pie chart with `styledMode: true;` and you import their highcharts.css file, the hover effect on legend items causes all legend items to go opaque.

[Code That Causes It](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/css/highcharts.scss#L260)

You can even see this on their [demo page](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/styled-mode-pie) by selecting the [Styled Mode: Pie](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/styled-mode-pie/).
And then hovering over the legends items. If you set the `styledMode: false;` and then remove the CSS import it goes away.

My question basically: Is this a bug? It seems like unintended behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it is a bug - it's more like a small difference between styledMode and the regular one, which could be easily fixed by changing the opacity for it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pq6omt2y/

CSS:

```
.highcharts-legend-point-active .highcharts-point:not(.highcharts-point-hover) {
  opacity: 1
}
```